# Make an UIImage from a CMSampleBuffer

Tags: ios, core-image, quartz-core

This is not the same as the countless questions about converting a `CMSampleBuffer` to a `UIImage`. I'm simply wondering why I can't convert it like this:

```
CVPixelBufferRef pixelBuffer = (CVPixelBufferRef)CMSampleBufferGetImageBuffer(sampleBuffer);
CIImage * imageFromCoreImageLibrary = [CIImage imageWithCVPixelBuffer: pixelBuffer];
UIImage * imageForUI = [UIImage imageWithCIImage: imageFromCoreImageLibrary];
```

It seems a lot simpler because it works for YCbCr color spaces, as well as RGBA and others. Is there something wrong with that code?

Comment: I know this question is old but this can serve as reference to other people. I just want to mention your first line: you are assigning a `CVImageBufferRef` coming from `CMSampleBufferGetImageBuffer` and casting it to a `CVPixelBufferRef`, two different things...

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/43470666/3939807 This Answer will help.

Answer (score 26, accepted):

With Swift 3 and iOS 10 AVCapturePhotoOutput :
Includes :

```
import UIKit
import CoreData
import CoreMotion
import AVFoundation
```

Create an UIView for preview and link it to the Main Class

```
  @IBOutlet var preview: UIView!
```

Create this to setup the camera session (**kCVPixelFormatType_32BGRA** is important !!) :

```
  lazy var cameraSession: AVCaptureSession = {
    let s = AVCaptureSession()
    s.sessionPreset = AVCaptureSessionPresetHigh
    return s
  }()

  lazy var previewLayer: AVCaptureVideoPreviewLayer = {
    let previewl:AVCaptureVideoPreviewLayer =  AVCaptureVideoPreviewLayer(session: self.cameraSession)
    previewl.frame = self.preview.bounds
    return previewl
  }()

  func setupCameraSession() {
    let captureDevice = AVCaptureDevice.defaultDevice(withMediaType: AVMediaTypeVideo) as AVCaptureDevice

    do {
      let deviceInput = try AVCaptureDeviceInput(device: captureDevice)

      cameraSession.beginConfiguration()

      if (cameraSession.canAddInput(deviceInput) == true) {
        cameraSession.addInput(deviceInput)
      }

      let dataOutput = AVCaptureVideoDataOutput()
      dataOutput.videoSettings = [(kCVPixelBufferPixelFormatTypeKey as NSString) : NSNumber(value: **kCVPixelFormatType_32BGRA** as UInt32)]
      dataOutput.alwaysDiscardsLateVideoFrames = true

      if (cameraSession.canAddOutput(dataOutput) == true) {
        cameraSession.addOutput(dataOutput)
      }

      cameraSession.commitConfiguration()

      let queue = DispatchQueue(label: "fr.popigny.videoQueue", attributes: [])
      dataOutput.setSampleBufferDelegate(self, queue: queue)

    }
    catch let error as NSError {
      NSLog("\(error), \(error.localizedDescription)")
    }
  }
```

In WillAppear :

```
  override func viewWillAppear(_ animated: Bool) {
    super.viewWillAppear(animated)
    setupCameraSession()
  }
```

In Didappear :

```
  override func viewDidAppear(_ animated: Bool) {
    super.viewDidAppear(animated)
    preview.layer.addSublayer(previewLayer)
    cameraSession.startRunning()
  }
```

Create a function to capture output :

```
  func captureOutput(_ captureOutput: AVCaptureOutput!, didOutputSampleBuffer sampleBuffer: CMSampleBuffer!, from connection: AVCaptureConnection!) {

    // Here you collect each frame and process it
    let ts:CMTime = CMSampleBufferGetPresentationTimeStamp(sampleBuffer)
    self.mycapturedimage = imageFromSampleBuffer(sampleBuffer: sampleBuffer)
}
```

Here is the code that convert an **kCVPixelFormatType_32BGRA** CMSampleBuffer to an **UIImage** the key things is the **bitmapInfo** that must correspond to **32BGRA** 32 little with premultfirst and alpha info :

```
  func imageFromSampleBuffer(sampleBuffer : CMSampleBuffer) -> UIImage
  {
    // Get a CMSampleBuffer's Core Video image buffer for the media data
    let  imageBuffer = CMSampleBufferGetImageBuffer(sampleBuffer);
    // Lock the base address of the pixel buffer
    CVPixelBufferLockBaseAddress(imageBuffer!, CVPixelBufferLockFlags.readOnly);


    // Get the number of bytes per row for the pixel buffer
    let baseAddress = CVPixelBufferGetBaseAddress(imageBuffer!);

    // Get the number of bytes per row for the pixel buffer
    let bytesPerRow = CVPixelBufferGetBytesPerRow(imageBuffer!);
    // Get the pixel buffer width and height
    let width = CVPixelBufferGetWidth(imageBuffer!);
    let height = CVPixelBufferGetHeight(imageBuffer!);

    // Create a device-dependent RGB color space
    let colorSpace = CGColorSpaceCreateDeviceRGB();

    // Create a bitmap graphics context with the sample buffer data
    var bitmapInfo: UInt32 = CGBitmapInfo.byteOrder32Little.rawValue
    bitmapInfo |= CGImageAlphaInfo.premultipliedFirst.rawValue & CGBitmapInfo.alphaInfoMask.rawValue
    //let bitmapInfo: UInt32 = CGBitmapInfo.alphaInfoMask.rawValue
    let context = CGContext.init(data: baseAddress, width: width, height: height, bitsPerComponent: 8, bytesPerRow: bytesPerRow, space: colorSpace, bitmapInfo: bitmapInfo)
    // Create a Quartz image from the pixel data in the bitmap graphics context
    let quartzImage = context?.makeImage();
    // Unlock the pixel buffer
    CVPixelBufferUnlockBaseAddress(imageBuffer!, CVPixelBufferLockFlags.readOnly);

    // Create an image object from the Quartz image
    let image = UIImage.init(cgImage: quartzImage!);

    return (image);
  }
```

Comment: `let image = UIImage.init(cgImage: quartzImage!);` doesn't work, I get next error `Thread 14: Fatal error: Unexpectedly found nil while unwrapping an Optional value`

Comment: I set  `videoOutput.videoSettings = [(kCVPixelBufferPixelFormatTypeKey as String) : NSNumber(value: kCVPixelFormatType_32BGRA as UInt32)]` and now it works, does it load device CPU more when I change format type? why default isn't kCVPixelFormatType_32BGRA initially?

Comment: @user924 By default it's in a BiPlanar format like `kCVPixelFormatType_420YpCbCr8BiPlanarVideoRange`, because this is more efficient to work with, as less bytes are required to represent the image

Answer (score 27):

For JPEG images:

**Swift 4:**

```
let buff: CMSampleBuffer ...            // Have you have CMSampleBuffer 
if let imageData = AVCapturePhotoOutput.jpegPhotoDataRepresentation(forJPEGSampleBuffer: buff, previewPhotoSampleBuffer: nil) {
    let image = UIImage(data: imageData) //  Here you have UIImage
}
```

Comment: Down voted because according to the documentation this will only work if the CMSampleBuffer is a JPEG image source, which is not mentioned in the answer, nor is it a requirement advocated by the question. For a significant number of use cases where the source is .H264 this will fail. https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/AVFoundation/Reference/AVCaptureStillImageOutput_Class/#//apple_ref/occ/clm/AVCaptureStillImageOutput/jpegStillImageNSDataRepresentation:

Comment: Correct ,  +[AVCaptureStillImageOutput jpegStillImageNSDataRepresentation:] Not a jpeg sample buffer.' 
Crashing in my case

Comment: I got `CRASH uncaughtExceptionHandler: *** +[AVCapturePhotoOutput JPEGPhotoDataRepresentationForJPEGSampleBuffer:previewPhotoSampleBuffer:] Not a jpeg sample buffer
2018-12-19 19:52:13.498514+0530 Stream[17414:2467572] *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '*** +[AVCapturePhotoOutput JPEGPhotoDataRepresentationForJPEGSampleBuffer:previewPhotoSampleBuffer:] Not a jpeg sample buffer'
`

Comment: @Luke Van In , it's right there `jpegPhotoDataRepresentation`.

Answer (score 14):

Use following code to convert image from PixelBuffer
Option 1:

```
CIImage *ciImage = [CIImage imageWithCVPixelBuffer:pixelBuffer];

CIContext *context = [CIContext contextWithOptions:nil];
CGImageRef myImage = [context
                         createCGImage:ciImage
                         fromRect:CGRectMake(0, 0,
                                             CVPixelBufferGetWidth(pixelBuffer),
                                             CVPixelBufferGetHeight(pixelBuffer))];

UIImage *uiImage = [UIImage imageWithCGImage:myImage];
```

Option 2:

```
int w = CVPixelBufferGetWidth(pixelBuffer);
int h = CVPixelBufferGetHeight(pixelBuffer);
int r = CVPixelBufferGetBytesPerRow(pixelBuffer);
int bytesPerPixel = r/w;

unsigned char *buffer = CVPixelBufferGetBaseAddress(pixelBuffer);

UIGraphicsBeginImageContext(CGSizeMake(w, h));

CGContextRef c = UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext();

unsigned char* data = CGBitmapContextGetData(c);
if (data != NULL) {
    int maxY = h;
    for(int y = 0; y<maxY; y++) {
        for(int x = 0; x<w; x++) {
            int offset = bytesPerPixel*((w*y)+x);
            data[offset] = buffer[offset];     // R
            data[offset+1] = buffer[offset+1]; // G
            data[offset+2] = buffer[offset+2]; // B
            data[offset+3] = buffer[offset+3]; // A
        }
    }
}
UIImage *img = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext();

UIGraphicsEndImageContext();
```

Comment: I'm looking for a reason why I can't use the three lines in my post. Also, does your method work with YCbCr 420f as well as RGBA? Wouldn't you need to access the separate planes independently?

Comment: because you need a context to capture your image. and context supports different types of context, you can change it as per requirement, it supports only RGBA, CMYK colorspace

Comment: How do I change the colorspace of a context from YCbCr to RGB?

Comment: basically there are there colorSpaces available in IOS,              CGColorSpaceCreateDeviceCMYK();
    CGColorSpaceCreateDeviceGray();
    CGColorSpaceCreateDeviceRGB();

Comment: You did not addressed the problem question: How to deal with CMSampleBuffer? It is not same as CVPixelBuffer

Comment: Note that  since iOS 6.0 there is a `+[UIImage imageWithCIImage:scale:orientation:]` method to go directly from your first line to a `UIImage`.

Comment: Important notice for **Option 1**.  You need to call `CGImageRelease(myImage);` after creating UIImage object.

Answer (score 12):

I wrote a simple extension for use with **Swift 4.x/3.x** to produce a `UIImage` from a `CMSampleBuffer`.

This also handles scaling and orientation, though you can just accept default values if they work for you.

```
import UIKit
import AVFoundation

extension CMSampleBuffer {
    func image(orientation: UIImageOrientation = .up, 
               scale: CGFloat = 1.0) -> UIImage? {
        if let buffer = CMSampleBufferGetImageBuffer(self) {
            let ciImage = CIImage(cvPixelBuffer: buffer)

            return UIImage(ciImage: ciImage, 
                           scale: scale,
                           orientation: orientation)
        }

        return nil
    }
}
```

1. If it can obtain buffer data from the image, it will proceed, otherwise nil is returned
2. Using the buffer, it initializes a `CIImage`
3. It returns a `UIImage` initialized with the `ciImage` value, along with the `scale` & `orientation` values. If none are provided, the defaults of `up` and `1.0` are used respectively

Answer (score 5):

Swift 5.0

```
if let cvImageBuffer = CMSampleBufferGetImageBuffer(sampleBuffer) {
   let ciimage = CIImage(cvImageBuffer: cvImageBuffer)
   let context = CIContext()

   if let cgImage = context.createCGImage(ciimage, from: ciimage.extent) {
      let uiImage = UIImage(cgImage: cgImage)
   }
}
```

Comment: Though it might seem redundant, in our case, going through `context.createCGImage` (vs simply calling `UIImage(ciImage:)`) correctly preserved the buffer's dimensions. Thanks!

Comment: why u create CIContect() everytime get samplebuffer?

Answer (score 4):

**TO ALL**: don't use methods like:

```
    private let context = CIContext()

    private func imageFromSampleBuffer2(_ sampleBuffer: CMSampleBuffer) -> UIImage? {
        guard let imageBuffer = CMSampleBufferGetImageBuffer(sampleBuffer) else { return nil }
        let ciImage = CIImage(cvPixelBuffer: imageBuffer)
        guard let cgImage = context.createCGImage(ciImage, from: ciImage.extent) else { return nil }
        return UIImage(cgImage: cgImage)
    }
```

they eat much more cpu, more time to convert

use solution from https://stackoverflow.com/a/40193359/7767664

don't forget to set next setting for AVCaptureVideoDataOutput

```
    videoOutput = AVCaptureVideoDataOutput()

    videoOutput.videoSettings = [(kCVPixelBufferPixelFormatTypeKey as String) : NSNumber(value: kCVPixelFormatType_32BGRA as UInt32)]
    //videoOutput.alwaysDiscardsLateVideoFrames = true

    videoOutput.setSampleBufferDelegate(self, queue: DispatchQueue(label: "MyQueue"))
```

convert method

```
    func imageFromSampleBuffer(_ sampleBuffer : CMSampleBuffer) -> UIImage {
        // Get a CMSampleBuffer's Core Video image buffer for the media data
        let  imageBuffer = CMSampleBufferGetImageBuffer(sampleBuffer);
        // Lock the base address of the pixel buffer
        CVPixelBufferLockBaseAddress(imageBuffer!, CVPixelBufferLockFlags.readOnly);


    // Get the number of bytes per row for the pixel buffer
    let baseAddress = CVPixelBufferGetBaseAddress(imageBuffer!);

    // Get the number of bytes per row for the pixel buffer
    let bytesPerRow = CVPixelBufferGetBytesPerRow(imageBuffer!);
    // Get the pixel buffer width and height
    let width = CVPixelBufferGetWidth(imageBuffer!);
    let height = CVPixelBufferGetHeight(imageBuffer!);

    // Create a device-dependent RGB color space
    let colorSpace = CGColorSpaceCreateDeviceRGB();

    // Create a bitmap graphics context with the sample buffer data
    var bitmapInfo: UInt32 = CGBitmapInfo.byteOrder32Little.rawValue
    bitmapInfo |= CGImageAlphaInfo.premultipliedFirst.rawValue & CGBitmapInfo.alphaInfoMask.rawValue
    //let bitmapInfo: UInt32 = CGBitmapInfo.alphaInfoMask.rawValue
    let context = CGContext.init(data: baseAddress, width: width, height: height, bitsPerComponent: 8, bytesPerRow: bytesPerRow, space: colorSpace, bitmapInfo: bitmapInfo)
    // Create a Quartz image from the pixel data in the bitmap graphics context
    let quartzImage = context?.makeImage();
    // Unlock the pixel buffer
    CVPixelBufferUnlockBaseAddress(imageBuffer!, CVPixelBufferLockFlags.readOnly);

    // Create an image object from the Quartz image
    let image = UIImage.init(cgImage: quartzImage!);

    return (image);
}
```

Answer (score 3):

This is going to come up a lot in connection with the iOS 10 AVCapturePhotoOutput class. Suppose the user wants to snap a photo and you call `capturePhoto(with:delegate:)` and your settings include a request for a *preview* image. This is a splendidly efficient way to get a preview image, but how are you going to display it in your interface? The preview image arrives as a CMSampleBuffer in your implementation of the delegate method:

```
func capture(_ output: AVCapturePhotoOutput, 
    didFinishProcessingPhotoSampleBuffer buff: CMSampleBuffer?, 
    previewPhotoSampleBuffer: CMSampleBuffer?, 
    resolvedSettings: AVCaptureResolvedPhotoSettings, 
    bracketSettings: AVCaptureBracketedStillImageSettings?, 
    error: Error?) {
```

You need to transform a CMSampleBuffer, `previewPhotoSampleBuffer` into a UIImage. How are you going to do that? Like this:

```
if let prev = previewPhotoSampleBuffer {
    if let buff = CMSampleBufferGetImageBuffer(prev) {
        let cim = CIImage(cvPixelBuffer: buff)
        let im = UIImage(ciImage: cim)
        // and now you have a UIImage! do something with it ...
    }
}
```

Comment: I have tried this, but there is a problem that the im without exif infomation(eg: orienation)

Comment: The exif information arrives separately. This is just the preview, nothing else.

Answer (score -1):

A Swift 4 / iOS 11 version of Popigny's answer:

```
import Foundation
import AVFoundation
import UIKit

class ViewController : UIViewController {
    let captureSession = AVCaptureSession()
    let photoOutput = AVCapturePhotoOutput()
    let cameraPreview = UIView(frame: .zero)
    let progressIndicator = ProgressIndicator()

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        setupVideoPreview()

        do {
            try setupCaptureSession()
        } catch {
            let errorMessage = String(describing:error)
            print("[--ERROR--]: \(#file):\(#function):\(#line): " + errorMessage)
            alert(title: "Error", message: errorMessage)
        }
    }

    private func setupCaptureSession() throws {
        let deviceDiscovery = AVCaptureDevice.DiscoverySession(deviceTypes: [AVCaptureDevice.DeviceType.builtInWideAngleCamera], mediaType: AVMediaType.video, position: AVCaptureDevice.Position.back)
        let devices = deviceDiscovery.devices

        guard let captureDevice = devices.first else {
            let errorMessage = "No camera available"
            print("[--ERROR--]: \(#file):\(#function):\(#line): " + errorMessage)
            alert(title: "Error", message: errorMessage)
            return
        }

        let captureDeviceInput = try AVCaptureDeviceInput(device: captureDevice)
        captureSession.addInput(captureDeviceInput)
        captureSession.sessionPreset = AVCaptureSession.Preset.photo
        captureSession.startRunning()

        if captureSession.canAddOutput(photoOutput) {
            captureSession.addOutput(photoOutput)
        }
    }

    private func setupVideoPreview() {

        let previewLayer = AVCaptureVideoPreviewLayer(session: captureSession)
        previewLayer.bounds = view.bounds
        previewLayer.position = CGPoint(x:view.bounds.midX, y:view.bounds.midY)
        previewLayer.videoGravity = AVLayerVideoGravity.resizeAspectFill

        cameraPreview.layer.addSublayer(previewLayer)
        cameraPreview.addGestureRecognizer(UITapGestureRecognizer(target: self, action:#selector(capturePhoto)))

        cameraPreview.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false

        view.addSubview(cameraPreview)

        let viewsDict = ["cameraPreview":cameraPreview]
        view.addConstraints(NSLayoutConstraint.constraints(withVisualFormat: "V:|-0-[cameraPreview]-0-|", options: [], metrics: nil, views: viewsDict))
        view.addConstraints(NSLayoutConstraint.constraints(withVisualFormat: "H:|-0-[cameraPreview]-0-|", options: [], metrics: nil, views: viewsDict))

    }

    @objc func capturePhoto(_ sender: UITapGestureRecognizer) {
        progressIndicator.add(toView: view)
        let photoOutputSettings = AVCapturePhotoSettings(format: [AVVideoCodecKey:AVVideoCodecType.jpeg])
        photoOutput.capturePhoto(with: photoOutputSettings, delegate: self)
    }

    func saveToPhotosAlbum(_ image: UIImage) {
        UIImageWriteToSavedPhotosAlbum(image, self, #selector(photoWasSavedToAlbum), nil)
    }

    @objc func photoWasSavedToAlbum(_ image: UIImage, _ error: Error?, _ context: Any?) {
        alert(message: "Photo saved to device photo album")
    }

    func alert(title: String?=nil, message:String?=nil) {
        let alert = UIAlertController(title: title, message: message, preferredStyle: .alert)
        alert.addAction(UIAlertAction(title: "OK", style: .default, handler: nil))
        present(alert, animated:true)
    }

}

extension ViewController : AVCapturePhotoCaptureDelegate {
    func photoOutput(_ output: AVCapturePhotoOutput, didFinishProcessingPhoto photo: AVCapturePhoto, error: Error?) {

        guard  let photoData = photo.fileDataRepresentation() else {
            let errorMessage = "Photo capture did not provide output data"
            print("[--ERROR--]: \(#file):\(#function):\(#line): " + errorMessage)
            alert(title: "Error", message: errorMessage)
            return
        }

        guard let image = UIImage(data: photoData) else {
            let errorMessage = "could not create image to save"
            print("[--ERROR--]: \(#file):\(#function):\(#line): " + errorMessage)
            alert(title: "Error", message: errorMessage)
            return
        }

        saveToPhotosAlbum(image)

        progressIndicator.hide()
    }
}
```

A full example project to see this in context: https://github.com/cruinh/CameraCapture

Comment: and where is `CMSampleBuffer`?

Comment: you didn't understand the question